# When instantiating multiple instances of a lua object when to use require vs new?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to wrap my head around the different ways to define and instantiate objects in Lua.

For the current problem, I'm imagining objects as simple as a C-struct (no methods necessary).

Between these two methods below, does it matter which way we choose? Is there a practical difference?  I'd like to go for "least code" because I like "less code" best.  It seems like the first method has a problem somewhere.  Maybe it's just me. What happens if we instantiate 10,000 mary's?  Does it matter?

First Way:

**mary.lua**

```
return {
  name = "mary"
}
```

**main.lua**

```
local r = require("mary")
local s = require("mary")
local t = require("mary")
local u = require("mary")
```

Second Way:

**mary.lua**

```
local _O = {}

function _O:new()
    o = {}
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    o:_create()
    return o
end

function _O:_create()
    self.name = "mary"
end

return _O
```

**main.lua**

```
local o = require("mary")
local r = o:new()
local s = o:new()
local t = o:new()
local u = o:new()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`require`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-require) is a function for loading modules, not instantiating classes.

`require("mary")` only loads `mary.lua` once, then stores the return value inside of `package.loaded["mary"]`. All subsequent results of `require("mary")` return the object at `package.loaded["mary"]`, and do not create new instances. This makes `require` unsuitable for class instantiating.

```
local r = require("mary")
local s = require("mary")
print(rawequal(r, s)) -- Prints true
r.name = "samantha"
print(s.name) -- Prints samantha
```

Your second way actually creates new class instances. However, instead of a `new` class method, it's more familiar to call the class table itself, using the `__call` metamethod. I've written a [one-file OOP framework](https://gist.github.com/ColonelThirtyTwo/7401493) that handles that and single inheritance; feel free to use it directly or as a reference.

Comment: For more advanced OOP libraries you might also check out MiddleClass https://github.com/kikito/middleclass